# Can't connect to mysql after failing due to low memory

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, out-of-memory

I have a mysql server running on an EC2 server lamp stack. It was running just fine, but the server ran out of memory and failed. I tried restarting mysqld but kept getting this error:

`mysqld dead but subsys locked`

So I created a swap file and now I am able to start mysqld, however, I cannot log in with the root user and password. I have searched the web, but couldn't find anything that was similar to my situation. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by following the instructions here: http://www.howtoforge.com/reset-forgotten-mysql-root-password